# How to import database from odoo 14 to postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, import, export, odoo

I am trying to take a backup from Odoo enterprise 14 through [query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqqyT.jpg).
When I try to export the dump file I get this [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsR5Y.jpg)
Can anyone guide me, how to export all the tables with data ?

Comment: Welcome to the SO community The community will help you with your issues, but there are certain expectations/requirements. One of them  do not post images, see [Why no images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Please take a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to review [ask].  BTW: it appears both links contain the same image..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply backup odoo database with this command :

```
pg_dump –format=c your_database_name > your_backup_name.dump
```

This will save your entire database to .dump format.